# Google Drive Custom Thumbnail for Standard MIME Type

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have yet another pesky question for people who understand how Google Drive SDK works. On Android platform, I am creating my own custom thumbnails for JPEG image files ( thumbnail is a reduced JPG of the most important detail of the parent image ), The size is a bit non-standard - 384 x 128px, but well within limits stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/file). So, the code goes like this:

```
// thumbnail 
String myThumb = "test.tnl";
Thumbnail tn = new Thumbnail();
tn.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
tn.setImage(Base64.encodeBase64String(myThumb.getBytes()));
 // define meta-data
File body = new File();
body.setTitle("test.jpg");
body.setDescription("bla bla");        
body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
body.setThumbnail(tn);
File gooFl  = drvSvc.files()
  .insert(body, new FileContent("image/jpeg", new java.io.File(test.jpg)))
  .execute();
```

and executes flawlessly (there are more 'body' elements I don't list here) and everything works like a charm. But when I download the image, my thumbnail is gone, replaced by standard Google thumbnail - s220 type.

I did notice the documentation statement:

> As with indexable text, Drive automatically generates thumbnails for many common file types. For shortcuts and other file types Drive can not render, you can provide a thumbnail image generated by your application.

Reading it ambiguously, I was hoping that by supplying my own thumbnail to a known MIME type, I will keep Google Drive from generating its standard one, but it probably is not the case. So the question remains. Is there a solution to my problem?  Having custom thumbnails for standard "image/jpeg" MIME types? Or is there a work-around, perhaps another custom field I can stick some 10Kb of binary data in? I need the thumbnails in my Android viewer - another app.

Thank you, sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive will only use custom thumbnails for non-standard MIME types, so you can't override the one for jpeg. Your app can use a custom file property to store and read proprietary data:

https://developers.google.com/drive/properties

Comment: Thank you Claudio, that's what I thought (but I've tried, anyway). I'm looking into your suggested solution (quite a new feature, I guess). Again, thanks a million. sean

Comment: When the documentation says "For shortcuts and other file types that Drive can't render", does this include large files with Standard MIME Types where Google Drive fails to create a thumbnail?

I see many large PDF (e.g. > 20 MB) or large JPG files (e.g. > 50 MegaPixels) in my Drive where no thumbnail image is displayed. I didn't find documentation on maximum sizes (in terms of bytes or pixels) that Google Drive can handle to render a preview.

My app generated previews for these large files and sent an update request via the API. It returns no error, but still no preview is visible.

Comment: @François the same here. I also tried to update thumbnails for big images, but with no success. API returned 200, but there is no thumbnails. I tried this to TIFs and PSDs, but no success? Is there known behaviour or what problem is?